# Conditions for positiveness of Brownian semi-martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Consider the Brownian semi-martingale

$$
p_t = \int_0^t\mu_s\,ds+\int_0^t\sigma_s\,dW_s,
$$
where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are cadlag processes and $W$ is a Brownian motion. 
Do there exist sufficient conditions for $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to guarantee that $p_t\geq 0$ path-wise?

Comment: Doléans-Dade Stochastic Exponential type process with correctly bounded jumps should be a sufficient class of processes to explore. Regards